# Piped value not updating

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

The "piped" value last is not updating except I recreate the piped object.
This is not my expected behaviour since I am building a timer in this way.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'fromNow'
})
export class FromNowPipe {
  transform(value: any, args: Array<any>): string {
    return moment(value).fromNow();
  }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'event-spinner',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default, // all other modes does not work at all
    pipes: [FromNowPipe],
    template: `
<div class="col-xs-5">
    NOT updating: {{ last | fromNow }} <br/>
    Updating: {{ lastText }} <br/>
</div>
  `
})
export class EventSpinner implements OnInit {
    last: moment.Moment;
    lastText: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.last = moment();
        let obs = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
            // this.last = moment(this.last); // uncommenting this line it updates
            this.lastText = this.last.fromNow();
            this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // commenting this line breaks everything 

        });
    }

}
```

What can I do to solve this issue in an clean way?
i.e. avoiding adding extra objects such as lastText or copying the moment object everytime from itself.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's because moment is intantiated outside the scope of Angular2 so you need to execute things within a zone:

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) { // <-----
}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.ngZone.run(() => { // <-----
    this.last = moment();
    let obs = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
        // this.last = moment(this.last); // uncommenting this line it updates
        this.lastText = this.last.fromNow();
        this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // commenting this line breaks everything 

    });
  });
}
```

**Edit**

In fact, the `fromNow` method updates the content of the `this.last` property not its reference. Angular2 detects changes based on reference changes. What you actually do with `he opens DHC for the first time`.